# data accessing isuue using pointer to the next node in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
 //first_link_list.c      This code Is not working                                                                                                                                                
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdlib.h>
  3 typedef struct{
  4 int data;
  5 struct link *next;
  6 }link;
  7 int main(){
  8     link *head = malloc(sizeof(link));
  9     link *first =  malloc(sizeof(link));
 10     link *second = malloc(sizeof(link));
 11     head->data = 35;       
 12     head->next = first;
 13     first->data=45;
 14     first->next=second;
 15     second->data = 55; 
 16     second->next = NULL;
 17     printf("VALUE of first element %d\n",*(first->next));   
 18 return 0;
 19 }
```

When I run 1st code It Gives Error/Warning Like This

```
first_link_list.c: In function main
first_link_list.c:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
first_link_list.c:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
first_link_list.c:17: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

What is went wrong,if i use "struct" instead of "typedef" the code works properly what is wrong in using typedef

Answer (score 2):

If you want to point to a struct inside the same type of struct you can name it before its contents like:

```
typedef struct link
{
   int data;
   struct link *next;
}
link;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, structs have a separate namespace. when you changed to a typedef, the struct has a typedef name, but no struct name. You can add a struct name:

```
typedef struct link_struct {  
   int data;
   struct link_struct *next;
} link;
```

Now you can refer to the struct type using either `struct link_struct` or the typedef name `link`.

Since structs have a separate namespace, you could use the name `link` for both the struct and the typedef. However, in C++ structs do not have their own namespace, so if you use the same name you cannot compile the code as C++.